# Why can't I choose option in select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to connect select from library `material ui`. I do not know for what reason I can not choose `option` and output in `state`? Someone faced with such a problem?

Detailed code example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zn5rm2j35l)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select/Select";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel/InputLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl/FormControl";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem/MenuItem";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    age: "",
    name: "hai"
  };
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.valueSelect });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <FormControl style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "27px" }}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-auto-width">Title</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: "hai",
              id: "age-simple"
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code: `this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.valueSelect });`

Change that to `event.taget.value`

That's coming from this value `value={this.state.age}` in your select...

And in general... cleaned up it would look like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { age: "" };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <FormControl style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "27px" }}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-auto-width">Title</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age"
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have many selects and they are render via map. Value applies to all at once.

Comment: Doesn’t matter... still has to be value... the concept is called a controlled input..

Comment: And if the structure state will be more difficult, I can not understand how to change each separately select `state = {

    exerciseItems: [
      {
        title: "Measurement type1",
        name: "Exercise Name",
        selectValue: ''
      },
      {
        title: "Measurement type2",
        name: "Exercise Name2",
        selectValue: ''
      },
      {
        title: "Measurement type3",
        name: "Exercise Name3",
        selectValue: ''
      }
    ]
  };`

Comment: As you can see in this example we have initialized state with age as an empty string... we also have name set to age in the input props in select... and we are using setState to set  event.target.name to the value we select... if you have more selects you have to initialize those in the state and follow the same pattern with input props...

Comment: for each select separate handle?

Comment: No that can stay the same as long as you follow the same pattern... with initializing in state and matching that with input props... So for example if you had another one let’s say zipcode your state would change to state = { age: “”, zipcode: “” } and then in your new select for zipcodes select input props you would add name: zipcode and of course in you menuitem the value / choices would be not 10, 20 etc (the age) but zipcodes

Comment: And I need to use `componentDidMount` ?

Comment: That’s usually used for ajax requests... so if you’re doing any data fetching from an API then yes,  but in this case if you’re initializing everything in state then no...

Comment: In all honesty you need to start with a react tutorial it sounds like...

Answer (score 2):

There's no `event.target.valueSelect`. Use `event.target.value`. And here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/98nl5jmjvr)